# Visual Studio 2013 После остановки Debug процессор остается в нагрузке

Tags: mvc, отладка, visual-studio-2013, процессор

После того как я останавливаю Debug режим в MVC проекте, процессор остается в нагрузке. Иконка IS Servera при этом исчезает из tray. В режиме ctr+F5 - так же, завершения IS Servera в tray не останавливает нагрузку на процессор.

Из дополнений в студии только Resharper. Помогает устранить эту проблему закрытие проекта - Close Solution, после чего - новый запуск проекта.

---

Списки запущенных процессов:

1. До запуска Debug (проект открыт).
2. В Debug - только запущен (проект открыт).
3. В Debug - при переходе на любую страницу (проект открыт).
4. Debug остановлен (проект открыт).
5. Проект закрыт.
6. Проект открыт (до запуска Debug).

**Фалы** - https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-3xJcP6pdRyflBFaHY5N1ZkUzFkQ0Q3cDUwTWJlcGN5eWtJRDVzaE13VENKSHpFVHlUcDg&usp=sharing

---

Помогите разобраться с проблемой. Если нужны еще какие то данные - напишите.

---

*VS 2013 Ultimate V12.0.31101.00 Update 4 (.Net Framework V4.5.51650)*

*Windows 8.1 Professional x64 English*

*HP ProBook 4540s (Intel i5-3210M, 8Gb DDR3)*

Comment: Из дополнений в студии только Resharper - это "только" - самый кушающий CPU аддон из всех. Вы пробовали его удалить?

Comment: Раньше пробовал переустановить Resharper, сейчас удалил его - разницы никакой. Дело не в нем, зависимости с ним нет.

Comment: Выяснилась новая информация по проблеме. Не в каждом проекте возникает данная проблема.